# My python code working perfect but exe not

Tags: python

After converting python code into exe its not working it giving me error.
I tried with autopytoexe and pyinstaller but problem is same.
This is error Im getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 267, in ssl_wrap_socket
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 360, in send
File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 542, in urlopen
File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 234, in connect
File "site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 269, in ssl_wrap_socket
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myfilename.py", line 19, in <module>
File "site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
File "site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
File "site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
File "site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[17864] Failed to excute script myfilename
```

EDIT:
My Module list

```
import time    
import requests    
import json
import re
from json import loads    
from datetime import datetime
import psutil
import platform
import socket
from requests import get
import os
import ftplib
import io
import urllib.request
import sys
```

EDIT : WARNING TXT

https://pastebin.com/SvQbZH9C

this is warning txt file that I got while creating exe file using pyinstaller

Comment: Please show the related code.  Looks like a relative path issue(?).

Comment: but my code working perfect there is only problem when i convert python code into exe.

Comment: You need to include the missing files by editing the `filename.spec` created after using pyinstaller. It is clearly stated https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html

Comment: but how to do this?
Im beginner , I dont know which file is missing.

Comment: Don't use ```--onefile``` to properly check which file is missing. Based on the error, i think the ```"site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py"``` is not included in the package. In ```/dist/folderName/``` is there a folder named ```requests```?

Comment: If not, you should include the whole requests module by putting this inside ```datas=[]``` in the ```.spec``` file:
```( 'C:/Users/klien/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/requests/*', 'requests')```

Comment: ohhh 
there is no named with requests I just have one file of code.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/6bfb76b407dfa88acdcb18e2b608464c
@KlienMenard

Comment: after doing this its same error.

Comment: @MGM after editing the ```.spec``` file, use ```pyinstaller fileName.spec```

Comment: also include the ```()``` in this sample ```( 'C:/Users/klien/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/requests/*', 'requests')```, hence making it like this:

```datas= [( 'C:/Users/klien/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/requests/*', 'requests')]```

Comment: @KlienMenard
can u check my edit again please .

Comment: Im getting this error.
https://gyazo.com/c557e3d8b077a153f08de753d4907edb
https://gyazo.com/9055a7089d503972a99df8d3087a89fe

Comment: i think you're missing the ```/site-packages/``` in you directory. include it before the ```/requests/*```

Comment: Check again the error in your post it has ```site-packages\``` before the ```\request```

Comment: I don't really think the ```warning.txt``` matters since the error output already told you what module is missing

Comment: 'C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util'
This is my directory where 'ssl_.py' find,

Comment: @MGM I'm aware that that is the directory of the missing file, What I'm trying to say is to include all the files/subfolders inside ```C:\Users\Ahmad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\requests\``` by stating it in the ```.spec``` file with this:

```datas = [('C:/Users/Ahmad/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Lib/site-packages/requests/*','requests')]```

Comment: I already tried this but when i tried to run pyinstallerfileName.spec it give error this
https://gyazo.com/c557e3d8b077a153f08de753d4907edb